# Loop in Laravel's schedule define

Tags: laravel, schedule

How can I loop through each row of a table and update them with different values in Laravel's schedule define?
I tried this for testing purposes in Kernel class but had an error:

```
$schedule->call(function () {
    $posts= Post::get();
    for( $i = 0; $i < count( $posts); $i++ ) {
        $posts[ $i ]>update([ 'title' => $i ]);
    }
})->everyMinute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to do this.**

```
   $schedule->call(function () {
      $posts= Post::all();
      foreach($posts as $post) {
          $post ->update([ 'title' => $i ]);
             }
   })->everyMinute();
```

**Post.php** should have title column fillable to update it through eloquent update method.

```
protected $fillable = ['title','other columns',...];
```

Answer (score 1):

You a have syntax error inside the loop:

```
$posts[ $i ]->update([ 'title' => $i ]);
```